# Invalid device id when using pytorch dataparallel！

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

## Environment：

- Win10
- Pytorch 1.3.0
- python3.7

## Problem：

I am using `dataparallel` in Pytorch to use the two 2080Ti GPUs. Code are like below:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = Darknet(opt.model_def)  
model.apply(weights_init_normal) 

model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1]).to(device)
```

But when run this code, I encounter errors below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PyTorch-YOLOv3-master/train.py", line 74, in <module>
    model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1]).to(device)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\envs\py37_torch1.3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 133, in __init__
    _check_balance(self.device_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\envs\py37_torch1.3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 19, in _check_balance
    dev_props = [torch.cuda.get_device_properties(i) for i in device_ids]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\envs\py37_torch1.3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    dev_props = [torch.cuda.get_device_properties(i) for i in device_ids]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\envs\py37_torch1.3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 337, in get_device_properties
    raise AssertionError("Invalid device id")
AssertionError: Invalid device id
```

When I debug into it, I find the function `device_count()` in `get_device_properties()` returns 1 while I have 2 GPU on my machine. And `torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount()` returns 2 in Anaconda Prompt. What is wrong?

## Qustion:

How to solve this problem?
How can I manage to use the two GPUs using dataparallel?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you please let me know the output of the following commands  
`torch.cuda.is_available()` and `torch.cuda.device_count()`. You installed Pytorch in a conda virtual environment, correct ?

Comment: Thank you for help. I have solved this by adding `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0, 1"` in my script. @JiteshMalipeddi

Comment: Great! Good to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically as pointed out by @ToughMind, we need specify

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0, 1"
```

It depends though on the CUDA devices available in one's unit, so if someone has one GPU it may be appropriate to put, for example,

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```